# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. in c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, file-upload, io, streamwriter

I am trying to Read a text file which is kept in a location of my PC Drive.

The  text file records Consist of 62 records but while Reading the file via Stream Reader in Catch I get following error which states the following

```
the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

I am able to insert 58 Record but in Catch i get 4 time Error stating the same.
In total 62 records= 62-4=58 records I am able to get.

Code as Follows:

```
  if (postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    sFileTempFullPath = postedFile.FileName;
                    doc = ReadWordDoc(sFileTempFullPath);
                    // ----------------------------------FileDate Append with the File Name which is Uploaded [FileDate ISO Code] --------------------------------------------------
                    fileDate = sFileTempFullPath.Substring((sFileTempFullPath.Length - 8)).ToString();
                    // -----------------------------FileName Append with the Full File Name which is Uploaded [FileName ISO Code] -----------------------------------------------
                    strFileName = sFileTempFullPath.Split('\\')[(sFileTempFullPath.Split('\\').Length - 1)].ToString();
                    // -----------------------------ISo Code Append with the Full File Name which is Uploaded [Retrive ISO Code] -----------------------------------------------
                    strISOcode = strFileName.Substring(0, 2);
                    if (strComDate == fileDate)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sFileTempFullPath))
                       {
                            //-------------------------------------------------------Saving for the File Name for e6 Files-------------------------------------------------------
                            Strcon.usp_UploadCountry(strISOcode, doc, strFileName, "e6", "AUTO");
                            Strcon.SaveChanges();
                        //Reading the First Line.
                        strLine = sr.ReadLine();
                            sub_Country(strLine, strFileName);
                            //Continue to read until you reach the end of the file.
                            int i = 0;
                            while (!(strLine == null))
                            {
                                strLine = sr.ReadLine();
                                sub_CountryIN(strLine, strFileName);
                            }
                            // sr.Dispose();
                            // sr.Close();
                        }
                        //-------------------------------------------------------Saving for the File Name for e6 Files-------------------------------------------------------
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Is the file being used by another process?

Comment: Find the process who locks your file and kill the process.

Comment: What do you mean by "Catch"? There is no exception handling in your code.

Comment: If it's your code that is working on the file in another process/thread, ensure that it allows for read sharing so that while it writes the file, other processes can still open to read it.

Comment: No the file is not used by any other process,How can we kill a process if i am using Stream Reader to read a file,I have not pasted the Exception handling Code but giving me the error message

Comment: `No the file is not used by any other process` How did you come to that conclusion? Could, for example, your anti-virus be reading it?

Comment: It is possible, that not another process read the file, but your code reads the file twice: Here `doc = ReadWordDoc(sFileTempFullPath);` and `new StreamReader(sFileTempFullPath)`. Depends on how the `ReadWordDoc` function works. Is the file closed after when the function ends? Additionally use sharing preferences when opening files _(**always**)_.